# Puzzled why I need to specify token for adding Node with Datastax OpsCenter

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I've been building a Cassandra cluster with Datastax's OpsCenter, on AWS, and finally have a live cluster up and running. Today I tried to add a node to the cluster, and I'm confused as to why OpsCenter is asking for a token for the node. I assume that vnodes are being used, so I should not have to supply a token for the new node? Note the "token" field with the "Nodes" label. Any help appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that your cluster uses vnodes? You can tell by looking for `num_tokens` in `cassandra.yaml` or by the view of the ring in OpsCenter (vnodes-enabled ring should be solid, vnodes-disabled should have separate coloured dots for nodes)